# Cannot instrument class XXX because it or one of its supertypes could not be initialized

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, java-17

Because jdk17 not compatible with, so i change to mockito 4.9.0. And that leads to @SuppressStaticInitializationFor will can't be used, but i need some classes not initialized statically

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
//@PrepareForTest({NonWorkingDayHelper.class, TaskService.class})
//@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.ecquaria.cloud.entity.nonworkingday.NonWorkingDayHelper")
public class TaskManagerTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        Mockito.mockStatic(NonWorkingDayHelper.class);
        Mockito.mockStatic(TaskService.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void testUpdateSLARemainInDays() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(NonWorkingDayHelper.isNonWorkingDay(any(Date.class))).thenReturn(false);
        Mockito.when(TaskService.getInstance()).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(TaskService.class));
        TaskManager.updateSLARemainInDays();

    }
}
```

[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8AuL.png)

in mockito 4.X, have any ways can Instead of @SuppressStaticInitializationFor